# SQL Query including SUM and GROUPBY

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by, sum

I'm creating a time tracking system, and i'm struggling with a fairly complex SQL query.

Basically i want to create a list of all the assignments for a particular module that currently have work sessions recorded, including the total time spent on each assignment.

So far i have used `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` to compare the `StartTime` and `EndTime` columns to calculate the total time spent on that particular work session as `TimeSpent`. However i'm struggling to understand how i would group the work sessions by `AssignmentID` and then `SUM()` all the `TimeSpent` columns together to give an overall total.

Here is what i have constructed so far.

```
SELECT t2.*, 
SUM( TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, t1.StartTime, t1.EndTime) ) AS TimeSpent 
FROM work_session t1 
LEFT JOIN assignment t2 ON t1.AssignmentID = t2.AssignmentID 
LEFT JOIN module t3 ON t2.ModuleID = t3.ModuleID 
LEFT JOIN course t4 ON t3.CourseID = t4.CourseID 
WHERE t2.ModuleID = 3
GROUP BY t1.AssignmentID
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. Also, note that your WHERE condition renders t3 as an INNER JOIN. If you want an OUTER JOIN, move that to the JOIN clause.

Comment: You need to include all the columns from the select in the group by clause for this to work. Also look in to Group By Grouping Sets((All columns))

Comment: @Jaypal MySQL allows selecting columns not listed in GROUP BY, it returns any of the values in the corresponding group.

Comment: Please tell us your problem. As far as I see it, your statement should work. Doesn't it?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Originally my results were showing a few negative numbers for the TimeSpent column. However after looking back through my work_session table i realised that some of the StartTimes were actually after the EndTimes. 

As you said, the statement itself was correct and worked fine. I just neglected to check that the data itelf was correct.

Many thanks for causing me to get back in the direction!

Comment: You are welcome. BTW: I guess, what you show us is just an excerpt of your original statement? The SQL as stated makes no use of tables module and course. These joins can be removed. And table assignment is actually inner joined so you should use INNER JOIN not LEFT JOIN for it.

Comment: I had actually just copied and pasted all those joins from another statement i had, to save me writing it out again. Howver I did realise earlier that there was no need for module and course to be in there.
I'm kind of a beginner when it comes to JOINS, so thanks for pointing that INNER JOIN out. Guess i better do a bit more reading on the subject. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To get the total, use [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) for "super aggregate" data:

```
SELECT t2.*, 
SUM( TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, t1.StartTime, t1.EndTime) ) AS TimeSpent 
FROM work_session t1 
LEFT JOIN assignment t2 ON t1.AssignmentID = t2.AssignmentID 
LEFT JOIN module t3 ON t2.ModuleID = t3.ModuleID 
LEFT JOIN course t4 ON t3.CourseID = t4.CourseID 
WHERE t2.ModuleID = 3
GROUP BY t1.AssignmentID
WITH ROLLUP
```

From the docs:

```
mysql> SELECT year, SUM(profit) FROM sales GROUP BY year;
+------+-------------+
| year | SUM(profit) |
+------+-------------+
| 2000 |        4525 |
| 2001 |        3010 |
+------+-------------+
```

with rollup:

```
mysql> SELECT year, SUM(profit) FROM sales GROUP BY year WITH ROLLUP;
+------+-------------+
| year | SUM(profit) |
+------+-------------+
| 2000 |        4525 |
| 2001 |        3010 |
| NULL |        7535 |
+------+-------------+
```